# How to Edit and Update an Data of a Table of ANT Design Table from Modals and Forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, antd

I have a problem here please anyone can help me? I have a trouble with Ant Design table here, in this table data I wanted to Create, Read, Update and Delete a data. Create, Read and Delete has been good and I can do it successfully, but on Edit data I couldn't figure it out.

The Data is already get and fetch by axios and fill it into the table.

To Create data when button "Add New Data' is pushed, there will be pop out a modals with form of creating new data like this picture below.

[image: modals Pop Out]

To Delete a data, when Delete Button is pushed there will be also pop out a confirmation pop out.

[image: Delete confirmation]

From this I can do it successfully, but on Edit data I couldn't figure it out how. Because I couldn't get the data and updated it. Please help me, and here's the sandbox code https://codesandbox.io/s/cattledata-9l2irf?file=/src/CattleData.js

Thank you and I would appreciate any helps.

Comment: What do you want is when you edit row data and click OK, then post data to update and get the updated data and show them in the table. Is it?

Comment: Yess, it is. I want to do it but for now I could'nt figure it out. Could you help me figure it out?